# event occuring multiple times

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have implemented a context menu on right click. On my menu, I have a button, on pressing it I `console.log("button is clicked");` message.

the problem I am facing is, first time on clicking, I am getting message **1 time**.
on the second time, on a single click, I am getting message **2 times**.
and so on like this...

Below is my jquery code:

```
$(document).on("contextmenu", function(event) {
    if ($(event.target).hasClass("sim-row-edit")) {  // sim-row-edit ended
        console.log("right click identified");
        .....
        // no problem in here
        // multiple occurance problem coming here
        $(".custom-menu li").click(function() {
            switch ($(this).attr("data-action")) {
                case "firstcase":
                    var thisDiv = target_element.closest('div');
                    console.log("Button is clicked");
                break;
                case "nextcase":
                ...

        $(document).on("mouseup", function() {
            $(".selected").removeClass("selected");
            $(".custom-menu").hide(100);
        });
```

html code:

```
<ul class='custom-menu'>
    <li data-action = "first">Clone</li>
    <li data-action = "second">Remove</li>
    <li data-action = "third">Edit</li>
</ul>
```

How do I get rid of this problem?

Comment: looks like you are registering click event handler multiple time .. can you share how you are registering it

Comment: i am just using the above code

Comment: Won't fix the problem, but should stop you seeing the evidence:  add `return false` to the end of the click handler (and any non-end exit points).

Comment: You *clearly* have more code than provided, eg `target_element`.  Something somewhere is registering additional click events.

Comment: Could you add also your html, please?

Comment: I right click on element, as many times i right click, all the messages occur once, but when i click on the menu link of context menu, this is happening

Comment: is your context menu inside .custom-menu, if so take it out

Comment: i have updated the question with html and more jquery code

Comment: .unbind() did the trick, in normal html jquery problem is not occuring, it occurs when i am using the same inside angular

Comment: You need to post a [mcve] which includes **_all_** the code to reproduce the issue.  That's the first time on this page that Angular has been mentioned.

Comment: Don't add event listeners inside a non unique event handler. Why do you even want it to be attached only from inside the contextmenu event?

Answer (score 1):

try this `event.stopPropagation()` :

```
$(".custom-menu li").click(function(e) {
  e.stopPropagation();
  switch ($(this).attr("data-action")) {
    case "firstcase":
  var thisDiv = target_element.closest('div');
  console.log("Button is clicked");
      break;

case "nextcase":
...
```

ref : https://api.jquery.com/event.stoppropagation/

Comment: where do you load this code ? is theres a possibility that it will load more than one time ?

Comment: the only case when i get your error is when i load that code multiple times check this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/anaselalami/xpvt214o/754033/)

Comment: try this `$(".custom-menu li").off('click').on('click',function(e) {`

Comment: you need to call that code out of `$(document).on("contextmenu", function(event) {`

Comment: .unbind() did the trick, in normal html jquery problem is not occuring, it occurs when i am using the same inside angular

Comment: cause each time `$(document).on("contextmenu", function(event) {` executed it bind click event to `$(".custom-menu li")`

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).on("contextmenu", function(event) {
    if ($(event.target).hasClass("sim-row-edit")) {  // sim-row-edit ended
        console.log("right click identified");
        .....
        // no problem in here
        // unbind click handler to avoid multiple occurance problem 
        $(".custom-menu li").unbind('click');
        $(".custom-menu li").click(function() {
            switch ($(this).attr("data-action")) {
                case "firstcase":
                    var thisDiv = target_element.closest('div');
                    console.log("Button is clicked");
                break;
                case "nextcase":
                ...

        $(document).on("mouseup", function() {
            $(".selected").removeClass("selected");
            $(".custom-menu").hide(100);
        });
```

Just unbind the previos click handler before adding handler again.As of jQuery 3.0, `.unbind()` has been deprecated. It was superseded by the `.off()`